# post_categories array using variable

Tags: categories, wp-insert-post

When using wp_insert_post can I do something like:

`$categories = '1,2,3,4,5'`

...and then...

`'post_category'  => array($categories)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the solution:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4018413/php-how-to-put-a-variable-in-an-array

`$categories = '1,2,3,4,5'`

...and then...

`'post_category' => explode(',', $categories)`

Answer (score 1):

There's an example here:
http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_insert_post

```
// Create post object
$my_post = array(
  'post_title'    => 'My post',
  'post_content'  => 'This is my post.',
  'post_status'   => 'publish',
  'post_author'   => 1,
  'post_category' => array(8,39)
);

// Insert the post into the database
wp_insert_post( $my_post );
```

'post_category' takes an array so you'd want to send it one.

In your example, you don't create an array - it's just a string.

```
$categories = '1,2,3,4,5';
```

This however is an array...

```
$categories = array( '1,2,3,4,5' );
```

So this should work:

```
'post_category' => $categories
```

For PHP arrays, check out:

http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_arrays.asp
https://www.php.net//manual/en/language.types.array.php